# Mysql Group concat and then queries based on results

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have a table business which has alot of many to many relationships. It was suggested i perform  a group concat first to get the ideas from the many table and then look at these ids to get the values from the many tables

In the below instance OK i can see i get a list of announcement ids back via the    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ba.announcement_id) as 'announcement', how from here do i set

SELECT * from announcement 
    where id IN(***_*__*_*__*_***)

where the in represents what was returned from the group_concat

id b

BEGIN

```
/* Business Information and Categories */
SELECT 
    b.alias_title, b.title, b.premisis_name, 
    a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.postal_code,tvc.town_village_city,spc.state_province_county, c.country,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT be.event_id) as 'event',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ba.announcement_id) as 'announcement', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bd.document_id) as 'document',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bi.image_id) as 'image',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bprod.product_id ) as 'product',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bt.tag_title_id) as 'tag'
    FROM business AS b
    INNER JOIN business_category bc_1 ON b.primary_category = bc_1.id
    INNER JOIN business_category bc_2 ON b.secondary_category = bc_2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business_category bc_3 ON b.tertiary_category = bc_3.id
    INNER JOIN address a ON b.address_id = a.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN town_village_city tvc ON a.town_village_city_id = tvc.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN state_province_county spc ON a.state_province_county_id
    INNER JOIN country c ON a.country_id = c.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN geolocation g ON b.geolocation_id = g.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business_event be ON b.id = be.event_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business_announcement ba ON b.id = ba.announcement_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business_document bd ON b.id = bd.business_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN business_image bi ON b.id = bi.business_id
    LEFT JOIN business_property bp ON b.id= bp.business_id
    LEFT JOIN business_product bprod ON b.id= bprod.business_id 
    LEFT JOIN business_tag bt ON b.id = bt.business_id
    WHERE b.id= in_business_id;

    SELECT * from announcement 
    where 




END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first select statement you may assign the announcementId's to a variable and then use it to get all announcements in the second query:

```
set @announcementIds = '';
select ...........,
@announcementIds:= GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT announcement_id) as 'announcement',
...........;

Select * from announcement 
where announcement_id REGEXP REPLACE(@announcementIds,',','|');
```

Some links:

- [Replace function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
- [Regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)